# Flutter Rotation X Y Imagen

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a problem, in the animation, the image rotates first on the X axis and then on the Y axis, but the image is upside down before it rotates. How do I make the image not to be visualized this way?

```
_controller = (widget.controller ??
    AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: widget.duration))
  ..addListener(() => setState(() {}))
  ..repeat();
_animation1 = Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 180.0).animate(CurvedAnimation(
    parent: _controller,
    curve: const Interval(0.0, 0.5, curve: Curves.easeIn)));
_animation2 = Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 180.0).animate(CurvedAnimation(
    parent: _controller,
    curve: const Interval(0.5, 1.0, curve: Curves.easeInOut)));


transform: Matrix4.identity()
          ..rotateX((0 - _animation1.value) * valorAngulo)
          ..rotateY((0 - _animation2.value) * valorAngulo),
```

This is my [**code**](https://gist.github.com/cristianfb1989/3eea933d9d612bb5db3aa87a67aab86a)

[image]

Comment: are you looking for a same-time rotation in both axis?

Comment: yes, I need that the image don't look like the gif shows